# Drawing on a Picturebox with an image in it and saving it

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm working on a program to take anvanced screenshots. But I'm stuck with a bug, I hope someone can help me.

- I can make screenshots with this code:

  ```
         // The screenshot will be stored in this bitmap.
      Bitmap capture = new Bitmap(screenBounds.Width, screenBounds.Height);

      // The code below takes the screenshot and
      // saves it in "capture" bitmap.
      g = Graphics.FromImage(capture);
      g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, screenBounds);

      // This code assigns the screenshot
      // to the Picturebox so that we can view it
      pictureBox1.Image = capture;
      pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

      // The code below make the form visible again, enables the "Save" button and stops the timer.
      this.Show();
      button2.Enabled = true;
      timer1.Stop();
  ```
- Drawing on the picturebox:

  ```
          color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
          Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
          g.FillEllipse(color, e.X, e.Y, 10, 10);
          g.Dispose();
  ```

**The problem:** I can only save the screenshot, not the drawings. 
I hope someone can help

Comment: Where is the code saving the `drawings`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `CreateGraphics()` - that's a temporary drawing.  Use your capture image:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(capture)) {
  g.FillEllipse(color, e.X, e.Y, 10, 10);
}
```